# SUM postgres not like expected

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sum, case, odoo

after the query I would like to obtain the SUM of account_move_line.balance AS ammounteur
when account_id, partner_id, invoice_id and account_account.code were =

```
SELECT     
    account_move_line.name, account_move_line.account_id,
    account_move_line.partner_id, account_move_line.invoice_id,
    account_move_line.journal_id,
    CASE 
       WHEN account_account.code LIKE '40%%'
          THEN '400000'
       WHEN account_account.code LIKE '44%%'
          THEN '440000'
       ELSE account_account.code    
    END AS ACCOUNTGL,
    CASE
       WHEN account_account.code = '702000' 
          THEN SUM(account_move_line.balance)
       ELSE (round(account_move_line.balance, 2))
    END AS AMOUNTEUR
FROM 
    public.account_move_line
JOIN 
    account_account ON (account_account.id = account_move_line.account_id)
WHERE 
    (account_move_line.date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-31')
GROUP BY  
    account_move_line.account_id, account_move_line.partner_id,
    account_move_line.invoice_id, account_move_line.journal_id,
    account_account.code, account_move_line.balance, account_move_line.name 
ORDER BY 
    account_move_line.account_id, account_move_line.invoice_id;
```

The result I get:

```
NAME                        account_id  Partner_id  Invoice_id J_id accountgl   amounteur
"Taxe led"                  186         2476        1883        1   "702000"    -0.83
"Taxe eclairage"            186         2476        1883        1   "702000"    -0.11
"Taxe gros et petit blanc"  186         3090        1884        1   "702000"    -0.83
"Taxe eclairage"            186         2077        1885        1   "702000"     0.25
"Taxe eclairage"            186         2077        1887        1   "702000"    -0.25
"Taxe eclairage"            186         2077        1888        1   "702000"    -0.02
"Taxe led"                  186         2481        1916        1   "702000"    -0.83
"Taxe eclairage"            186         2481        1916        1   "702000"    -0.52
```

I expected

```
NAME                        account_id  Partner_id  Invoice_id J_id accountgl   amounteur
                            186         2476        1883       1    "702000"    -0.94
"Taxe gros et petit blanc"  186         3090        1884       1    "702000"    -0.83
"Taxe eclairage"            186         2077        1885       1    "702000"     0.25
"Taxe eclairage"            186         2077        1887       1    "702000"    -0.25
"Taxe eclairage"            186         2077        1888       1    "702000"    -0.02
                            186         2481        1916       1    "702000"    -1.35
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, but it seems you expect the results to be grouped by account_id, partner_id, invoice_id, and perhaps journal_id. But you've told it to group by so many more columns.

```
account_move_line.account_id,
account_move_line.partner_id,
account_move_line.invoice_id,
account_move_line.journal_id,
account_account.code,
account_move_line.balance,
account_move_line.name
```

To be grouped, a row would have to have the same account, partner, invoice, and journal IDs. Plus the same code, balance, and name.

Cut your group by back to just the four IDs.

This will mean you cannot select some columns because the group has several values for that column. For example, the name. Each group will contain several names, no single name can be selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I try to remove account_account.code, account_move_line.balance,account_move_line.name from my group by I have an issue for example  about  « account_account.code » postgresql error column must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @ChristopheCarion As with name, the group will have many codes; asking for one code doesn't make sense. You could group by that column, but as you've discovered that changes your groupings. You could [aggregate the codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html). Or you can drop it from the select list. I can't tell you which is the right choice for your query.